# maven tomcat7:shutdown

Tags: tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

I start my application using mvn tomcat7:run and its working but when I use mvn tomcat7:shutdown to stop it its showing build success but the embedded tomcat is not shutting down
I get this result

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
com.xxx.yy.ci:ci:war:1.0.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found d
uplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
@ line 95, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CI Web Application 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:shutdown (default-cli) @ ci ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.391s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 10 14:32:04 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mvn tomcat7:run need to use ctrl+c to shutdown as it's attached to the current maven run.
So you don't need to use shutdown goal.
Maybe I miss something ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But in which case I can use shutdown goal?

Comment: If you fork the run mojo then after tests execution use shutdown.

Comment: but when I run plugin in fork mode I get this error                                                       Exception in thread "hudson initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
        at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
der.java:1713)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
der.java:1558)
        ... 1 more

Comment: @rohan lukose, do you know how to shutdown tomcat7 correctly with command 'mvn tomcat7:shutdown'? if yes, please, provide an example.